# Voltage Doubler Circuit

Tags: capacitor, multiplier, charge-pump, voltage-doubler

I currently have a 25 stage voltage doubler circuit
I am using 50 0.1 uF x2 suppression capacitors, 50 1N4007 Diodes, and a 20 Mohm current limiting resistors at the final emitter stage. I am using 120 VAC as the initial input voltage.

I would like to increase my output voltage so I am interested in buying a higher value capacitor.

For example, if I upgrade to a 10 uF capacitor (100 times more powerful than current setup) will I need to change any other components of my circuit (e.g. the diodes)?

Comment: What current do the diodes currently take?

Comment: These diodes are rated for 1A

Comment: That is not what I asked.

Comment: This is a highly dangerous circuit so I am not comfortable measuring the current. I do know that the current in this circuit is negligible. It is an ionizer circuit. I just don't feel safe measuring current across a singular diode. Is there any other way I can help you? I just need to know the effects of upgrading my capacitors on the circuit. What should I consider?

Comment: Try using LTSpice to simulate it - that's another option. You'd be surprised how big the current pulses can be.

Comment: A cockroft-walton type thing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator  If so, the value of the capacitors sets the maximum current and not the voltage.  If you want more voltage start with more voltage.  This is good. http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/

Comment: So what results are ppl exactly getting by increasing capacitor size? What is the usefulness in increasing capacitor size? Increasing current doesn't help the Ionizer circuit very much since it is dependent on output voltage.